# How to parse integers and operators within an array with Javascript?

Tags: arrays, dom

I am trying to code a calculator app with HTML, CSS and JavaScript and so far have been able to populate an array with numbers and operator symbols for the display.

I am trying to find a way to separate the numbers (as integers) from the operators and hope to then run an operation function on them later to complete the calculation.

However, I am really struggling to separate the numbers and operators. a typical array looks like this:

`["9", "8", "7", "+", "3"]`

I have looked into `join()` and `parseInt()` but cannot see how to determined the differences between array elements in loops.

please find my full JS and HTML code below. Any advice would be much appreciated.

JS

```
const add = (num1, num2) => num1 + num2
const subtract = (num1, num2) => num1 - num2
const multiply = (num1, num2) => num1 * num2
const divide = (num1, num2) => num1 / num2
let textView = document.querySelector('input[data- 
view]')
let calculation = []

// type numbers into the calculator display.
document.querySelector('div[data-behavior="btn- 
container"]').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (e.target.dataset.input === 'number') {
calculation.push(e.target.value)
textView.value = calculation.join('')
}
})
// type operators into the calculator display
document.querySelector('div[data-behavior="btn-container"]').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (e.target.dataset.input === 'operator') {
    calculation.push(e.target.value)
    textView.value = calculation.join('')
  }
})
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='calculator-container'>
      <div class = 'display-container'>
        <form>
          <input data-view class = 'textView'>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class = 'button-container' data-behavior='btn-container'>
        <button class = 'number'data-input = 'number' value = 7>7</button>
        <button class = 'number'data-input = 'number' value = 8>8</button>
        <button class = 'number'data-input = 'number' value = 9>9</button>
        <button class = 'operatot' data-input = 'operator' value = />/</button>
        <button class = 'number'data-input = 'number' value = 4>4</button>
        <button class = 'number'data-input = 'number' value = 5>5</button>
        <button class = 'number'data-input = 'number' value = 6>6</button>
        <button class = 'operator' data-input='operator' value = X >X</button>
        <button class = 'number' data-input = 'number' value = 1>1</button>
        <button class = 'number'data-input = 'number' value = 2>2</button>
        <button class = 'number'data-input = 'number' value = 3>3</button>
        <button class = 'number'data-input = 'number' value = 0>0</button>
        <button class='operator' data-input='operator' value = ->-</button>
        <button class='operator' data-input='operator' value = +>+</button>
        <button data-behavior='equals'>=</button>
        <button data-behavior='clear' value = 'clear'>AC</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="calculator.js" ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is that it looks to me like you haven't fully worked out how you want your calculator to behave. What happens when you push an operator button before you push a number button? What happens if you hit two numbers in a row? Will you support decimals, or just integers? (You might have already decided not to.) Where's the equals button? Where's the clear button?

The second thing is that you've dived into coding without fully working out your logic. If I were doing this, I would set up two click event handlers, one for your `number` class and one for your `operator` class. The logic for each is unrelated, so they shouldn't be part of the same function (functions should basically stick to doing one thing). I would have three variables: the first number, the selected operator and the second number; I would also have one array as you do. I would also add an equals button and a clear button. (For the clear button I would add another event handler specific to it, and give it its own class name.) My logic would run something like this:

1. Get a number from user. Store to your array.
2. As long as the user keeps hitting number buttons, keep pushing them onto the array.
3. When the user hits an operator, store it to `currentOperator` or whatever you want to call it. Parse your array into an integer. Store result to `num1`. Empty your array.
4. Get another number from user, store to your array, repeat step 2.
5. When the user hits the equals button, parse your array into an integer again. Store result to `num2`. Evaluate `currentOperator`. Perform the appropriate operation and display the result.
6. If the user hits clear, empty your array and reset your variables.

Whatever you wind up doing, you need to know what it is before you start writing it. Writing code doesn't tell you what code to write.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will go back and plan again from the start more comprehensively.

Comment: You're very welcome. It may help to think of software development as having four basic phases: decide what you're going to do, decide how you're going to do it, do it, and stabilize it. It's important to be rigorous in distinguishing the first two phases from one another; it's very easy to wander off into "hows" when you're defining "whats," munge them all together in your mind, and miss things. It isn't that you have to get all the "whats" before you start working on the "hows," but you do need to be conscious of when you move from the one to the other and get in the habit of moving back.

Comment: Thank you agin, have actually gone back as you suggested, much much easier second time around :)

Comment: @J.Day Good job. As Lincoln was supposed to have said, if I had six hours to chop down a tree, I would spend five of them sharpening the axe. :)